# Invalid BigNumber error when converting number fetched from NextRouter

Tags: ethers.js, bignumber, nextjs, router

I'm fetching a listing number for an item listed on a marketplace contract and then formatting it to ethers BigNumber. I'm getting error:

invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

I'm using router.isReady to make sure listing ID is fetched before running the command. What else could be the issue?

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (router.isReady) {
        setListingIdFormatted(BigNumber.from(listingId.listingid));
        console.log(listingId.listingid);
      }
    }, [router.isReady]);

    // load direct listing
    useEffect(() => {
        async function listingEvents() {
          if (listingIdFormatted) { // Check if nft is defined
            const nft = await marketplace?.directListings.getListing(listingIdFormatted);
            setNft(nft);
          }
        }
        listingEvents();
      }, [listingIdFormatted]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
```

Means that you are calling an function that receives an argument but this argument is undefined. Review your code based on this information.